# Universal quantification and unification, an example

Tags: haskell, types

Given the following signature for running the monad `ST`

```
runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a
```

and the functions

```
newVar  :: a -> ST s (MutVar s a) 
readVar :: MutVar s a -> ST s a
```

Then the Haskell compiler will reject the following ill-typed expression

```
let v = runST (newVar True)
in runST (readVar v)
```

Because in order to evaluate `runST`, it's required that the type

```
readVar v :: ST s Bool
```

must be generalized to

```
∀s . ST s Bool
```

My question is then that the only job of the Universal quantifier here, is to ensure that the type variable `s` is always free in the context of evaluation avoiding generalization, am I right? or is there more about the universal quantifier here?

Comment: What do you mean by "always free in the context of evaluation avoiding generalization"? I think you probably have the right idea about this but I can't parse the sentence.

Comment: please correct if I'm wrong. Generalization of the type t in the context Γ, requires the quantification of the free variables of t that do not occur free on Γ. What I mean then is that since s is both free in t and  Γ, the type can't be generalized, then is rejected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's read the type of `runST`. I added an explicit quatifier for `a` as well.

```
runST :: forall a . (forall s. ST s a) -> a
```

It reads as the following contract:

1. the caller chooses a fixed type `a`
2. the caller provides an argument `x`
3. the argument `x` must be of type `ST s a` for any choice of `s`. In other words, `s` will be chosen by `runST`, not by the caller.

Let's see a similar example:

```
runFoo :: forall a . (forall s. s -> [(s,a)]) -> [a]
runFoo x =
    let part1 = x "hello!"          -- here s is String
        -- part1 has type [(String, a)]
        part2 = x 'a'               -- here s is Char
        -- part2 has type [(Char, a)]
        part3 = x (map snd part2)   -- here s is [a]   (!!!)
        -- part3 has type [([a],a)]
    in map snd part1 ++ map snd part2 ++ map snd part3

test1 :: [Int]
test1 = runFoo (\y -> [(y,2),(y,5)])   -- here a is Int

test2 :: [Int]
test2 = runFoo (\y -> [("abc" ++ y,2)])       -- ** error
-- I can't choose y :: String, runFoo will choose that type!
```

Above, note that `a` is fixed (to `Int`), and that I can't put any restrictions on the type of `y`. Moreover:

```
test3 = runFoo (\y -> [(y,y)])    -- ** error
```

Here I am *not* fixing `a` in advance, but I'm trying to choose `a=s`. I am not allowed to do that: `runFoo` is allowed to choose `s` in terms of `a` (see `part3` above), so `a` must be fixed in advance.

Now, to your example. The problem lies in

```
runST (newSTRef ...)
```

Here, `newSTRef` returns a `ST s (STRef s Int)`, so it's trying to choose `a = STRef s Int`. Since `a` depends on `s`, this choice is invalid.

This "trick" is used by the `ST` monad to prevent references to "escape" from the monad. That is, it is guaranteed that after `runST` returns, all the references are now no longer accessible (and potentially they can be garbage collected). Because of this, the mutable state which was used during the `ST` computation has been thrown away, and the result of `runST` is indeed a *pure* value. This is, after all, the main purpose of the `ST` monad: it is meant to allow (temporary) mutable state to be used in a pure computation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing something. The actual message GHCi gives is:

```
Prelude> :m +Control.Monad.ST
Prelude Control.Monad.ST> data MutVar s a = MutVar
Prelude Control.Monad.ST> :set -XRankNTypes
Prelude Control.Monad.ST> data MutVar s a = MutVar
Prelude Control.Monad.ST> let readVar = undefined :: MutVar s a -> ST s a
Prelude Control.Monad.ST> let newVar = undefined :: a -> ST s (MutVar s a)
Prelude Control.Monad.ST> runST $ readVar $ runST $ newVar True

<interactive>:14:27:
    Couldn't match type ‘s’ with ‘s1’
    ‘s’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a type expected by the context: ST s Bool at <interactive>:14:1
    ‘s1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a type expected by the context: ST s1 (MutVar s Bool)
        at <interactive>:14:19
    Expected type: ST s1 (MutVar s Bool)
    Actual type: ST s1 (MutVar s1 Bool)
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘newVar True’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘runST $ newVar True’
```

The Haskell compiler rejects it not because of *anything* to do with `readVar` but rather because of a problem with `newVar`, which is that `ST s (MutVar s a)` allows the `s` to "escape" its context by jumping into the `MutVar` expression.