# ST's use of RankNTypes to make its interface pure

Tags: haskell, types, monads, mutation

As I understand it, Haskell's ST monad is unique in that it allows me to describe a computation that locally uses mutable memory, but still presents a pure interface. That is, it allows me to mutate memory so long as that mutation doesn't escape the computation. The simplest example of this would be something like:

```
runST $ newSTRef "trying to return a memory reference."
```

This results in a compile time error (how cool!):

```
Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘STRef s a0’
  because type variable ‘s’ would escape its scope
This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
  a type expected by the context: ST s a
  at <interactive>:1:1-18
Expected type: ST s a
  Actual type: ST s (STRef s a0)
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘newSTRef 0’
In the expression: runST $ newSTRef 0
```

My understanding is that if a mutable reference is allowed to escape the computation, it could be mutated elsewhere, and my ST computation might no longer have a pure interface (it might return different values on different invocations).

My question is: How is this implemented? I see that the definition of runST and newSTRef make heavy use of RankNTypes, but I'm having trouble understanding how these types produce the compile error above.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28840303/3234959) of mine partially answers this.

Comment: @AlexBeal close as duplicate then?